# spark-submit --master local[n] cannot create multi-threads

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I write pyspark code to deal with some spark-sql data.

Last month, it worked perfectly when I ran `spark-submit --master local[25]`. From `top` command, I could see 25 python threads.

However, nothing change but today the spark-submit only create one thread. I wonder what kind of things can cause such problem.

This is on a ubuntu server on AWS, which has 16 CPU cores. The Spark version is 2.2.1 and Python is 3.6

Comment: Can you check if there are any jobs running on the cluster occupying resources

Comment: Using AWS EMR or self built cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Just find the problem: there is another user running his own spark task on the same instance which occupying resources.